# Saving numpy arrays as part of a larger text file

Tags: python, numpy

How can I save NumPy arrays as part of a larger text file? I can write the arrays to a temp file using `savetxt`, and then read them back into a string, but this seems like redundant and inefficient coding (some of the arrays will be large). For example:

```
from numpy import *

a=reshape(arange(12),(3,4))
b=reshape(arange(30),(6,5))

with open ('d.txt','w') as fh:
    fh.write('Some text\n')
    savetxt('tmp.txt', a, delimiter=',')
    with open ("tmp.txt", "r") as th:
        str=th.read()
    fh.write(str)
    fh.write('Some other text\n')
    savetxt('tmp.txt', b, delimiter=',')
    with open ("tmp.txt", "r") as th:
        str=th.read()
    fh.write(str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter of [savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

> **fname** : filename or ***file handle***

So, you can open file in [append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python) and write to it:

```
with open ('d.txt','a') as fh:
  fh.write('Some text\n')
  savetxt(fh, a, delimiter=',')
  fh.write('Some other text\n')
  savetxt(fh, b, delimiter=',')
```